# Can the square of the distance between two points be used when determining the minimum value of euclidian distance?

Tags: calculus

Let's say I have a function for the distance between two moving points in a 2d plane.

The functions to describe the position of the first point is:

$$x_{1}(t) = v_{x1}\times t + x_{1_{0}}, 0 <= t < t_{end}$$
$$y_{1}(t) = v_{y1}\times t + y_{1_{0}}, 0 <= t < t_{end}$$

and analogously for $y_{2}(t)$ and $x_{2}(t)$.

Then, the distance between the two points is:

$$D(t) = \sqrt{(v_{x1}\times t + x_{1_{0}}-v_{x_{2}} \times t-x_{2_{0}})^2+(v_{y_{1}}\times t + y_{1_{0}}-v_{y_{2}} \times t-y_{2_{0}})^2}$$

I need to find the smallest distance between the two points in $0<t<t_{end}$. It would be a lot easier for me to do this if I could work with $D^2(t)$ instead of $D(t)$ when deriving the function, finding the roots of the derivative and checking the second derivative. Thus, my questions are:

1. Are the maximum and minimum points of $D$ and $D^2$ the same? In other words, is the derivative of each function equal to $0$ for the same $t$?
2. Do the highest and lowest values occur for the same value of t on $0<t<t_{end}$ for $D$ and $D^2$?
3. Does a positive second derivative in combination with the first derivative being equal to zero for a value $t_{n}$ indicate a minimum point for $D^2$ just like for $D$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1: Yes: to minimize $D(t)$ is to minimize $D(t)^2$, and so on.

2: The highest and lowest values of $D(t)$ and $D(t)^2$ are attained by the same $t$ values.

3: Yes, with a possible exception in the special case $D(t)=0$ which you can think about later.  ($D(t)$ won't be differentiable for $t$ values for which $D(t)=0$, but $D(t)^2$ will.)  It is of course easier to work out first and second derivatives of $D(t)^2$ than of $D(t)$; you can use the chain rule to get the latter from the former without too much trouble.

Comment: I'm sorry about question 2, corrected it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Thank you.  I've edited my answer for 2.